# How can I change the username for the logged in user?

Tags: asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

After scaffolding in the view files for Identity, I'm looking at `Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Manage\index.cshtml` to see if I can somehow set the user name to something other than the e-mail address. In the view, the input field for `Username` is `disabled`:

```
<input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" disabled />
```

I removed "`disabled`", entered a name and saved the form, but the e-mail address just popped back.

I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental here. It has to be possible for users to have real names in a membership system?

**UPDATE**
I found this tutorial, but now I'm too tired to read it. I will give it a go in the morning:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: What's your identity provider? You should probably update the question with some more details.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the field `Username` is not intended to hold the user's full name, but that you should add fields like full name, date of birth, etc. to the base class as needed.

This piece of documentation describes how to do that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Yea you better off inherit from the base `IdentityUser` class and add what you need there.

#### 1. Inherit from `IndentityUser`

```c#
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DL.SO.Infra.CrossCutting.Identity.Entities
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string DisplayName => $"{ FirstName } { LastName }";

        public AppUserStatus Status { get; set; }
    }

    // This is in separate file, but for simplicity I would just add it here
    public enum AppUserStatus
    {
        Active = 1,
        Inactive = 2
    }
}
```

You see here I've added first name, last name field, as well as a status to the application user entity.

#### 2. Create `DbContext` from correct overload

If you add additional information on the base `IdentityUser` (actually any identity classes you've changed) or want to change the type of the primary key, you need to create the `DbContext` using the correct overload it provides.

```c#
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using DL.SO.Infra.CrossCutting.Identity.Entities;

namespace DL.SO.Infra.CrossCutting.Identity
{
    public class AppIdentityDbContext
        : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, int, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole,
             AppUserLogin, AppRoleClaim, AppUserToken>
    {
        public AppIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityDbContext> options)
            : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<AppUser>(b =>
            {
                // Rename the column Id to UserId (optional)
                b.Property(u => u.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");

                b.ToTable("User");
            });
            builder.Entity<AppRole>().ToTable("Role");

            builder.Entity<AppUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
            builder.Entity<AppUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
            builder.Entity<AppRoleClaim>().ToTable("RoleClaim");
            builder.Entity<AppUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
            builder.Entity<AppUserToken>().ToTable("UserToken");
        }
    }
}
```

#### 3. Register Identity Framework at Startup

You then need to use your custom `DbContext` and classes when registering the Identity framework at `Startup.cs`. Here I demo using extension method but you can also put them inside the `Startup.cs` directly.

```c#
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using DL.SO.Infra.CrossCutting.Identity.Entities;
using DL.SO.Infra.CrossCutting.Identity.Settings;
using System;

namespace DL.SO.Infra.CrossCutting.Identity.Extensions
{
    public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static void AddIdentityService(this IServiceCollection services,
            string connectionString, AppIdentitySettings settings)
        {
            string assemblyNamespace = typeof(AppIdentityDbContext).Namespace;

            services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, optionsBuilder =>
                    optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(assemblyNamespace)
                )
            );

            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options =>    // <-- Your custom classes
            {
                // User settings
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = settings.User.RequireUniqueEmail;

                // Password settings
                options.Password.RequireDigit = settings.Password.RequireDigit;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = settings.Password.RequiredLength;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = settings.Password.RequireLowercase;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = settings.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = settings.Password.RequireUppercase;

                // Lockout settings
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = settings.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers;
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(settings.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpanInMins);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = settings.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>()    // <-- Your custom DbContext
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        }
    }
}
```